# How to sort an array alphabetical order in both directions with the click of a button

Tags: java, android

I have an Array that contain list of countries.
I have one button that sorting the array by abc while i'm clicking on it.
I want that when i click on the same button again, it will sort the array by cba .
Ascending and descending order.

Here is the method that sorting my array.

```
public void sortByNativeName() {
        Collections.sort(mCountries, new Comparator<Country>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Country o1, Country o2) {
                return o1.getNativeName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getNativeName());
            }
        });
        updateAdapter(mCountries);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Collections.reverse](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List%3C?%3E)) method for that:

```
public void sortByNativeName() {
        Collections.sort(mCountries, new Comparator<Country>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Country o1, Country o2) {
                return o1.getNativeName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getNativeName());
            }
        });
        if(reverseResult){
            Collections.reverse(mCountries);
        }
        updateAdapter(mCountries);
    }
```

And then on the OnClick switch the boolean value after click:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
      sortByNativeName();
      reverseResult = !reverseResult;
}
```

Don't forget to declare reverseResult boolean as global

Comment: Thanks Your very much, it's work. How can I make the same sort but with Double variables?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<Country> mCountries;
ListView listview;
CustomAdapter adapter;
boolean isAssending = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);
    mCountries = new ArrayList<>();
    listview = findViewById(R.id.listview);

    mCountries.add(new Country("England"));
    mCountries.add(new Country("India"));
    mCountries.add(new Country("France"));
    mCountries.add(new Country("Reunion"));
    mCountries.add(new Country("Nepal"));

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, mCountries);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}
public void sortData(View view) {
    if (isAssending) {
        Collections.sort(mCountries, new Comparator<Country>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Country o1, Country o2) {
                return o2.getNativeName().compareToIgnoreCase(o1.getNativeName());
            }
        });
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        isAssending=false;
    }
    else {
        Collections.reverse(mCountries);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        isAssending=true;
    }
}
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<Country> mCountries;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Country> mCountries) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mCountries = mCountries;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCountries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, false);
        TextView textview = v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textview.setText(mCountries.get(i).getNativeName());
        return v;
    }
}
class Country {
    private String nativeName;
    public Country(String nativeName) {
        this.nativeName = nativeName;
    }
    public String getNativeName() {
        return nativeName;
    }
    public void setNativeName(String nativeName) {
        this.nativeName = nativeName;
    }
}}
```